# XSD validation fails because null value is invalid decimal

Tags: xml, xsd, null, xml-validation

i have a problem writing a valid XSD which describes a potential null-value for a decimal.

I'm trying to validate following XML

```
<RatioDe fieldId="011" nil="true"></RatioDe>
```

and the corresponding XSD description for this element is

```
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RatioDe" nillable="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
          <xs:attribute name="fieldId" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:attribute name="nil" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Basically, the errormessage is

> The element 'RatioDe' is invalid - The value '' is not a valid 'Decimal' -- The string '' is not a valid decimal value

At the moment i have no further idea what to change in my xsd to make the xml valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `xsi:nil` in your instance document, not just `nil`, i.e.

```
<RatioDe fieldId="011" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

And make sure that the `xsi` prefix is defined somewhere in the document (with `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`)